# MySql query lock after full text search

Tags: mysql, locking, full-text-search

- MySQL engine: InnoDB
- MySql version: 5.6.31

1.Run first simple query

```sql
SELECT o.id
FROM tbl_oper o
WHERE o.id_oper_tip = 8 AND o.id_oper_naim = 6;
```

**result: 7 rows**

2.Run full text search on same table

```sql
SELECT
    o.id,
    MATCH(o.full_text_search) AGAINST('7930' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 'match'
FROM tbl_oper o
WHERE 0 < MATCH(o.full_text_search) AGAINST('7930' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

**result: 6 rows (no matter)**

3.Repeat first query, **result: 0 rows**, but full text search still return 6 rows

4.Queries without "AND" keyword work normally:

```sql
SELECT o.id
FROM tbl_oper o
WHERE o.id_oper_tip = 8
```

7 rows

```sql
SELECT o.id
FROM tbl_oper o
WHERE o.id_oper_naim = 6
```

500+ rows

5.The first query will work only after reboot. Why?

Same result when queries are runs from IDE, shell, php-app

Create statement for tbl_oper:

```sql
CREATE TABLE 'tbl_oper' (
    'id'                INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'id_oper_naim'      INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_oper_tip'       INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'num'               VARCHAR(20)               DEFAULT NULL,
    'data_oper'         DATE                      DEFAULT NULL,
    'time_oper'         VARCHAR(20)               DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_sotrZ'          INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_fiz_deb'        INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_yur_deb'        INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_podrazdel_deb'  INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_fiz_kred'       INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_yur_kred'       INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_podrazdel_kred' INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_nds_stavka'     INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'summa'             DECIMAL(10, 2)            DEFAULT NULL,
    'summa_nds'         FLOAT                     DEFAULT NULL,
    'comment'           TEXT,
    'prov'              INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'num_kred'          VARCHAR(20)               DEFAULT NULL,
    'prem'              INT(11)                   DEFAULT NULL,
    'id_dealer'         INT(10) UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    'full_text_search'  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
    KEY 'id_podrazdel_kred' ('id_podrazdel_kred'),
    KEY 'id_oper_naim' ('id_oper_naim'),
    KEY 'id_oper_tip' ('id_oper_tip'),
    KEY 'id_yur_deb' ('id_yur_deb'),
    KEY 'id_podrazdel_deb' ('id_podrazdel_deb'),
    KEY 'id_yur_kred' ('id_yur_kred'),
    KEY 'id_fiz_deb' ('id_fiz_deb'),
    KEY 'id_nds_stavka' ('id_nds_stavka'),
    KEY 'ct_oper_sotrz_idx' ('id_sotrZ'),
    KEY 'ct_oper_fiz_kred_idx' ('id_fiz_kred'),
    FULLTEXT KEY 'full_text_search' ('full_text_search'),
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_oper_fiz_deb' FOREIGN KEY ('id_fiz_deb') REFERENCES 'tbl_person' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_oper_fiz_kred' FOREIGN KEY ('id_fiz_kred') REFERENCES 'tbl_person' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_oper_naim' FOREIGN KEY ('id_oper_naim') REFERENCES 'spr_oper_naim' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_oper_sotrz' FOREIGN KEY ('id_sotrZ') REFERENCES 'tbl_person' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_oper_type' FOREIGN KEY ('id_oper_tip') REFERENCES 'spr_oper_tip' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_podrazdel_deb' FOREIGN KEY ('id_podrazdel_deb') REFERENCES 'tbl_podrazdel' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_podrazdel_kred' FOREIGN KEY ('id_podrazdel_kred') REFERENCES 'tbl_podrazdel' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_yur_deb' FOREIGN KEY ('id_yur_deb') REFERENCES 'tbl_yur' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT 'ct_yur_kred' FOREIGN KEY ('id_yur_kred') REFERENCES 'tbl_yur' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 38357
    DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to repair table?

See also:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Comment: can you share the create table statement of tbl_oper with indexes?0

Comment: extend my first post

Comment: Just I noticed:

Comment: Just I notised query without AND work normally:

`SELECT COUNT(o.id)
FROM tbl_oper o
WHERE o.id_oper_naim = 6`

Comment: DROP AND RECREATE FULLTEXT INDEX do not help ((

Comment: Do you try it from your program?  What kind of client do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I reduced database to 1 table, 9 rows, 3 indexes. This is minimal set to repeat bug;
There are no foreign keys, indexes only.

```
CREATE TABLE `operations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_id_idx` (`name_id`),
  KEY `type_id_idx` (`type_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_idx` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


id | name_id | type_id | description
---+---------+---------+------------
1  | 2       | 3       | "hello world"
2  | 3       | 1       | "pascal"
3  | 3       | 1       | "geeen apple"
4  | 6       | 8       | "deep hell"
5  | 5       | 1       | NULL
6  | 3       | 1       | NULL
7  | 2       | 3       | NULL
8  | 3       | 4       | NULL
9  | 6       | 8       | NULL
```

First query work if:

- server restart
- reindex any index
- remains *single* row with `name_id = 6` and `type_id = 8`

This bug checked on version 5.6.31, 5.6.34

**Upgrade to 5.7.16 solved problem;**